# does the pip installer respect existing pip configurations?

Tags: python, deployment, pip

I am trying to deploy pip following this guide:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
If i deploy a pip.conf specifying the index server will the installer respect it and fetch the packages from there?